# Angular4 and firebase Uncaught(in promise) TypeError cannot read property of 'push' of undefined

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I am quite new in angular, but I have managed my way through it and learn how to use it thanks to its awesome documentation and lots of tutorials out there. I have a rather strange problem. In my app, I'm using firebase and angualrfire2 library. I call these libraries in my service and then I call my service in my component. When I serve and test the app in my localhost I try to submit an entry into firebase real time database as objectObservable and I get this error being logged in my browser's console, "Uncaught(in promise) TypeError: cannot read property 'push' of undefined in firebase.servise.ts:34 . And believe me, I have tried all solutions on the internet peculiar to this and still no solution. I need help. 
My service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabase} from 'angularfire2/database';
import { FirebaseObjectObservable} from 'angularfire2/database';
import { FirebaseListObservable} from 'angularfire2/database';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';



@Injectable()
export class FirebaseService {
registors: FirebaseListObservable<any>;
registor: FirebaseObjectObservable<any>;
folder:any;

 constructor( private db:AngularFireDatabase) { 
 this.folder = 'registor';

   }

      getRegistors(){
      this.registors = this.db.list('/registors') as 
    FirebaseListObservable<Registor[]>;
     return this.registors;
    }

   //create function to push to firebase
     addRegistor(registor){
   let storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();
   for(let selectedFile of 
  [(<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById('image')).files[0]] ){
  let path =`/${this.folder}/${selectedFile.name}`;
  let iRef = storageRef.child(path);
  iRef.put(selectedFile).then((snapshot) => {
    registor.headshot = selectedFile.name;
    registor.path = path;
    return this.registors.push(registor);

  });
}
```

}

}
 And My component

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
   import {FirebaseService} from '../../services/firebase.service';
    import {Router} from '@angular/router';

   @Component({
   selector: 'app-register',
  templateUrl: './register.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./register.component.css']
 })
   export class RegisterComponent implements OnInit {
           fullname:any;
       dateofbirth:any;
      city:any;
        height:any;
         phone:any;
      email:any;
        whatsapp:any;
   instagram:any;
   modelling:any;
     makeup:any;
      fashion:any;
    entrepreneurship:any;
  selfMsg:any;
         headshot:any;

     constructor( private firebaseService:FirebaseService, 
  private router:Router) { }

 ngOnInit() {
   }

        onAddSubmit(){
     let registor ={
       fullname : this.fullname,
         dateofbirth: this.dateofbirth,
         city: this.city,
       height: this.height,
     phone: this.phone,
      email:this.email,
    whatsapp:this.whatsapp,
      instagram: this.instagram,
       modelling: this.modelling,
          makeup:this.makeup,
         fashion:this.fashion,
           entrepreneurship:this.entrepreneurship,
             selfMsg: this.selfMsg
         }
              this.firebaseService.addRegistor(registor);

              this.router.navigate(['/']);
          }

        }
```

Comment: Can you share a small amount of code that reproduces the error?

Comment: Your post has not changed. And don't past images of code, just past the code itself. StackOverflow has 'special' formatting for this, see https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting

Comment: Is it really that hard to format/indent your code properly?

Comment: Where are you calling `getRegistors`? Without calling it, `this.registors` will be undefined.

Comment: Ohk so that is for later part of the code so i guess i'll have to comment it out but that is also not working still getting ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined